# Is there a way to add a field to core feed aggregator for Drupal 7?

Tags: rss, drupal-7

When I click "Add feed", it only allows me to input the title and URL.  I am looking to fetch all the feeds into a single page.  Seems like the core aggregator is doing that just right. However I want to add a new field called "Name" to display who contributes the feeds. I looked into the feeds module but it breaks feeds into nodes instead of displaying all the feeds in a single node.  There is probably a way to do it with feeds module but I can't seem to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would expect the feed reader to aggregate the nodes into a feed, not drupal itself. Using feedburner or similar intermediate step you can add all manner of other stuff to your feed.

You can also use views to create feeds, might help you get the granularity you need. I think views 3 on D7 can do it natively, but you can certainly get modules for it: http://drupal.org/project/views_rss